# Partially transparent scatter plot, but with a solid color bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter, colorbar

In Python, with Matplotlib, how to simply do a scatter plot with transparency (alpha < 1), but with a color bar that represents their color value, but has alpha = 1?

Here is what one gets, with `from pylab import *; scatter(range(10), arange(0, 100, 10), c=range(10), alpha=0.2); color_bar = colorbar()`:

[image]

How can the color bar be made non-transparent?

**PS**: I tried `color_bar.set_alpha(1); draw()`, but this did not do anything…

Comment: But since it's a scatter plot, what would the color bar indicate? Should it correspond to the size of each point, `s`, or the color of each point, `c`?

Comment: @Steve: The color bar would map the color of the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478725/partially-transparent-scatter-plot-but-with-a-solid-color-bar/76848051#comment57238631_4480124) is the correct way to do this as matplotlib 6.0 has deprecated `cbar.draw_all()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.scatter(range(10), range(10), c=range(10), alpha=0.2)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
cbar.solids.set(alpha=1)
```

The deprecation warning:
`MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The draw_all function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use fig.draw_without_rendering() instead. cbar.draw_all()`

Comment: Interesting. Could you share a reference to the deprecation? I'll be ready to change the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @EricO.Lebigot I've added the depreciation warning to my post.

Comment: @joe-kington happy for you to make your own answer... it is your work after all :)

Answer (score 46):

Alright, I found one way to do it, that looks relatively clean: (using the `ColorBar` object from the question)

```
color_bar.set_alpha(1)
color_bar.draw_all()
# pylab.draw() or pyplot.draw() might be necessary
```

It would be great to get a confirmation that this is the most robust way to proceed, though! :)

Comment: What if I don't want the colorbar labels?  `draw_all()` makes the labels appear even if I have set `color_bar.ax.set_yticklabels([])`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this… I tried to clear the color bar axes first (`color_bar.ax.cla()`), but then drawing the colorbar again with `draw_all()` fails.

Comment: On a side note, you can also use `cbar.solids.set(alpha=1)` if you'd prefer not to call `draw_all()` for any particular reason (e.g. custom labels, etc).

Answer (score 15):

This is a huge, ugly hack. But no other way would work. Maybe someone else can improve.

```
fig1 = pylab.figure()
fig2 = pylab.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(range(10), range(10), c=range(10), alpha=0.2)
im = ax2.scatter(range(10), range(10), c=range(10), alpha=1.0)
fig1.colorbar(im, ax=ax1)
fig1.show()
```

[image]

Comment: +1: interesting idea!  One drawback is that you get an additional figure when `pyplot.show()` is called (that could be destroyed, arguably…).

Comment: Indeed, it creates a new figure. That was really a "last resort" solution.  :-)