# Display Matrix with a gradient of Alpha

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matrix

I have Matrix of shape (100,100) which I'm visualising as an image but I'd like the values closest to zero to display increasingly transparent (alpha = 255). How can I acheieve this?

Current code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.imshow(pricesM15, interpolation='bicubic')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Amsterdam house prices]

Edit: I have tried one of the solutions listed below. The alpha gets applied to the low range and not around zero.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# Random data
data1 = difference

# Choose colormap
cmap = pl.cm.RdBu

# Get the colormap colors
my_cmap = cmap(np.arange(cmap.N))

# Set alpha
my_cmap[:,-1] = np.linspace(0, 1, cmap.N)

# Create new colormap
my_cmap = ListedColormap(my_cmap)

pl.figure(figsize=(16, 7))
pl.subplot(121)
pl.pcolormesh(data1, cmap=pl.cm.RdBu)
pl.colorbar()

pl.subplot(122)
pl.pcolormesh(data1, cmap=my_cmap)
pl.colorbar()

save_fig("two_plots")
```

[image: Amsterdam house prices difference]

Comment: Did you try anything yet, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327308/add-alpha-to-an-existing-matplotlib-colormap). It's really hard to help, if people don't show at which point they get stuck.

Comment: I've added one of my attempts, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ok, so the zero is not necessarily at the bottom of the colormap, is that the problem? Are you looking for a solution for zero being in the middle then? What should the alpha values for the lower end of the colormap be in that case?

Comment: If your data range is symmetric about zero, and you want the colours closest to 0 to be more transparent, you could just change the line in your example above to:  `my_cmap[:,-1] = np.abs(np.linspace(-1, 1, cmap.N))`, which sets alpha to 1 at each end, and 0 in the middle.