# Heat maps in python - with colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I try to make a program for plotting a heat map based on the clicks from the participants. There are two bodies with increase and decrease emotions.

I want to show the intensity of clicks on the left body with blue color (more intense blue = more number of clicks) and right body with red color.

The problem is that I need to show it in one body and also with the background image over which I see the heat map.

```
x=blue[:,1]
y=blue[:,2]
ax = plt.gca()

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()

x1=red[:,1]
y1=red[:,2]
ax = plt.gca()

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x1, y1, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
plt.imshow(image)

imageFile = cbook.get_sample_data('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\pythonpca\\result.png')
image = plt.imread(imageFile)
plt.plot(all_samples[0:240,0],all_samples[0:240,1], 'o', markersize=3, color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='increase')
plt.imshow(image)
```

By this I get a heat map for the left body clicks, a heat map for right body clicks and a picture of the left and right bodies. I want them all in the same picture, with blue and red hotspots. I am attaching the pictures I get with this.

2 bodies picture (I have plotted blue points on it, but I do not need the points):

[image: 2 bodies picture ( I have plotted blue points on it, but I do not need the points]

The heat maps from the left and right bodies:

[image: the heat maps from the left and right bodies]

Please let me know if I should add more info.

Comment: maybe you should take a look at `seaborn` it's a nice wrapper for matplotlib, and also have some nice heatmaps

Comment: if you can express back and front by e.g. positive and negative numbers you can use a diverging color map https://matplotlib.org/users/plotting/colormaps/lightness_03.png
https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html#diverging
I guess your approach is fine so far, you just have to translate the coordinates of the right plot to the left one, e.g. by subtracting the offset from the x values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two different colors to represent left vs right-body clicks, and use the opacity (alpha channel) to represent the density of clicks within a given region. One way to do this would be to create a custom [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20colors%20linearsegmentedcolormap#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap) that varies in the alpha channel:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

# Some fake data
nbins = (50, 50)
ranges = ((-2, 2), (-2, 2))
lx, ly = np.random.randn(2, 10000) * 0.5 + 1
rx, ry = np.random.randn(2, 10000) * 0.75 - 1

# Compute 2D histograms
left_density = np.histogram2d(lx, ly, bins=nbins, range=ranges, normed=True)[0]
right_density = np.histogram2d(rx, ry, bins=nbins, range=ranges, normed=True)[0]

# Make some custom colormaps that vary in the alpha channel.
trans2blue = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    name='Trans2Blue', colors=[(0., 0., 1., 0.), (0., 0., 1., 1.)])
trans2red = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    name='Trans2Red', colors=[(1., 0., 0., 0.), (1., 0., 0., 1.)])

# `imshow` the histograms using the custom colormaps.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
left_im = ax.imshow(left_density, cmap=trans2blue)
right_im = ax.imshow(right_density, cmap=trans2red)

right_cb = fig.colorbar(right_im)
right_cb.set_label('Right click density')
left_cb = fig.colorbar(left_im)
left_cb.set_label('Left click density')

# Workaround for https://stackoverflow.com/q/15003353/1461210
left_cb.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
right_cb.solids.set_edgecolor("face")

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Another way to achieve the same effect would be to construct two `(rows, cols, 4)` arrays of RGBA pixel values where the alpha channel contains your density values, and RGB contains your desired color, then `imshow` these on top of one another. Using a custom colormap has a few advantages though - the colormap range gets scaled automatically, and it's fairly easy to add colorbars.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @ArunSubraminion Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it addresses your question.

Comment: can I ask how to add a background image to this ? Also, if I would like to add PCA to this program based on where the participants have clicked so that I could differentiate different test cases, how can I do it ? I mean I would like to find for which emotion the area where people clicked was strange.

Comment: Since the overlaid histogram images are semi-transparent, you could just `imshow` your background image in the same set of axes before `imshow`ing your two heatmap arrays on top. How to perform PCA is really a totally separate question, so I'm not going to try to answer it in the comments here. Before you open a new question, try searching on StackOverflow first, since there are already lots of existing answers explaining various ways to perform PCA in Python, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1730600/1461210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13224362/1461210).